# Breaking a loop

Tags: python

Hello im trying to make an mp3 player. At the moment Im just trying to get it to print the found mp3 file to the console but its stuck in an infinate loop and Im not sure how to break it as im still new to python

```
def mp3_finder():
    times_done = 5
    starting = 0
    for file in os.listdir(full_dir):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            while starting < times_done:
                starting = starting + 1
                print(file)

    return mp3_finder()
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry i wasnt very clear but what im trying to do is find the mp3 file and print the name to the console 5 times but because it keeps finding the file it keeps printing it to the console until python stops it because it printed hundreds of it

Comment: You're calling the function again in the return statement; what are you actually trying to do? Even removing the unneeded `return` statement, it looks like this would `print` the first file 5 times, then nothing more. Show your desired output.

Comment: @Cyphase - that is the root cause, you should post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: The reason it's repeating 100's of times (likely 1000 times, to be precise), is because you were calling the function again at the bottom of itself, so it kept calling itself again and again until it hit the recursion limit. As for what you want, do you only want to find 1 MP3 file and print it out 5 times? Or do you want to print each MP3 file 5 times? Your code does the latter, though it still iterates over all the files, just without printing them.

Comment: Thank you I see what you mean and have deleted the return (I had that in there because of other code ive written (Im still very new at this)) and its working now thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function again in the return statement; since you're `print`ing within the function, you can just remove the `return` entirely.

```
def mp3_finder():
    times_done = 5
    starting = 0
    for file in os.listdir(full_dir):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            while starting < times_done:
                starting = starting + 1
                print(file)
```

That answers your question about breaking a loop, but perhaps you should ask another one about your code, because I don't think it's going to give you the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should probably not call `mp3_finder` at the end of the function - it will recurse infinitly. Also you probably don't want the inner loop, it wil just print the first file five times. Combined the result will be that the function prints the first file five times, then it calls itself which again prints the first file five times and so on until you reach maximum recursion depth.

What you want to return isn't clear maybe it's OK to just return `None` (ie skip the `return` statement entirely). Second you'll need to `break` out of the loop when you're done.

```
def mp3_finder():
    times_done = 5
    starting = 0
    for file in os.listdir(full_dir):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            if starting < times_done:
                starting = starting + 1
                print(file)
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def mp3_finder():
   times_done = 5
   starting = 0
   for file in os.listdir(full_dir):
     if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        while starting < times_done:
            starting = starting + 1
            print(file)

mp3_finder()
```

Watch your indent otherwise looks good

Comment: You should watch your indent yourself ;). Also, once you fix the indentation, how is this code different?

Comment: His return statement is in his method definition. So it'll circular reference. I'm pretty sure in his code he's meaning to call it once

Comment: I know, but why do you have the `return` there?